# Why do I get a syntax error when I assign a variable?

Tags: python

I am a beginner in programming and  am having an issue i cant solve. I am using python 3.7.3. I am  writing a simple exercise for encoding transversal through a while loop. I get a syntax error on 'index'. I have assigned index to 0. But don't know why it registers a syntax error when using it.

```
index = 0
name = 'Micheal' 
while index < len(name):
    letter = name[index]
    print(letter)
    index = index + 1
```

I know that the formatting is wrong in this post but i had trouble putting the code into this thread.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you post the full traceback? Also is `Micheal` a variable somewhere as I'd expect `name = Micheal` to throw a `NameError` if not...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to apply code formatting. To render a line of text as code, start the line with 4 spaces, or highlight the code and press `Ctrl K` (on Mac, `Cmd K` also works).

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler How did you know that the indentation was not the cause of the syntax error?

Comment: Not reproducible. Getting `NameError: name 'Micheal' is not defined`. Did you mean `name = 'Micheal'`?

Comment: @Selcuk No way to know for sure; hoping OP can follow up. Other commenters have pointed out two syntax errors which need fixing regardless of indentation.

Comment: Sorry forgot to quote Micheal. But I am getting a syntax error only in the line While index <len(name)

Comment: As currently presented, this code does not reproduce the error you describe. (Or any error, for that matter. It runs just fine.)

Answer (score 1):

`"Micheal"` should be quoted so it's a string and not a variable, and in Python 3, you need to add parentheses for the `print` function.

```
index = 0
name = 'Micheal' 
while index < len(name):
    letter = name[index]
    print(letter)
    index = index + 1
```

Comment: Thank you ! I have updated my code to this but still get a syntax error on 'index' in the while index< len(name) line.

Comment: If you don't mind, can you show the error message?

Comment: 'invalid syntax' with index highlighted red

Comment: That's strange, im also using Python 3.7.3 and it runs fine for me

Comment: [url=https://ibb.co/8X7SRFm][img]https://i.ibb.co/zN40LKm/PXL-20211206-033038407.jpg[/img][/url]

Comment: That page doesn't exist

Comment: @DK `While` is capitalized. Make it `while`.

Comment: @EricssonCui Probably a formatting issue, this is the actual link: https://i.ibb.co/zN40LKm/PXL-20211206-033038407.jpg

Comment: I ran it again it worked for me now.  Thank you ! Don't know what went wrong. I must of done something previously.

Comment: Well, that would be the case, you capitalized the "W" in "while", just as what krmoji said

Comment: Thank you so much !  I feel soo dumb ahah